# solr StandardTokenizer: how is underscore processed with wildcards?

Tags: java, solr

So, I have a Solr instance which processes inputs and queries using `StandardTokenizer` (as well as `ClassicFilterfactory`, `LowercaseFilterFactory` and `Stopfilterfactory`).

In my index are a number of files with underscore separated names (eg. `some_indexed_file.jpg`).

I've noticed that if I query for `some_indexed_file.jpg`, I get the file I'm looking for returned correctly.

However, if I alternatively search for `some_indexed_file.jp*`, (that's with an asterisk, which I am presuming is acting as a wildcard) which, by my understanding should produce similar results, I get no results.

Any idea what's going on: I assume I'm misunderstanding something about the way solr processes queries?

**Edit**: as requested, here are the schema XML configuration entries:

```
    <fieldType name="default" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>



   <field name="filename" type="default" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false" termVectors="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you please add the following to your question: excerpts from schema.xml with <field> and <fieldType> definitions for the field where you are storing and/or searching for the filename in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a bit more research has solved the problem: 
The base issue is that Solr doesn't apply text analysis to wildcard queries.

This meant that it was searching for an exact match to `some_indexed_file.jp*`. However, when the filename was indexed, it was tokenised into "some" "indexed" and `file.jpg`, which does not match this search term.
Searching for `some_indexed_file.jpg` was being tokenised properly, and therefore returning the right results.

Comment: Had the same problem here. How did you fix it? :(

Comment: I actually haven't fixed it yet. The simplest method we could think of was to pre-process the query to remove underscores. That is a bit of a bodge, though.

Comment: Was a better solution ever found?